# Where to place a callback in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes it's intuitive and sometimes I just have no clear idea of where to place `callback` in the function to create a proper callback.  Can you show me where it would go in here? - and explain?  Thanks...

```
var callSlides = function(my_elem, name, callback) {

  $(my_elem).one('inview', function (event, visible) {

    if (visible) {

      $(my_elem + ' .photo-list .photo03').html('<img src="images/people/' + name + '/02.jpg" alt="" />');
      $(my_elem + ' .photo-list .photo04').html('<img src="images/people/' + name + '/03.jpg" alt="" />');  // <-- here somewhere ?

    }
  });  // <-- here somewhere ?

};
```

with an expected outcome something like this?

```
callSlides('#marc-leviste', 'leviste', function() {
  // do the next things
});
```

This makes sense to me...

```
function sheriff(speed, callback) {
    $('.thing').method(speed, callback);
}
```

So, using the top example... I think I would put it in one of the the .html('', callback);

Would that make sense ?

Comment: Where to put it? Do you mean where to *invoke* it? That would depend entirely on the intent of the code. Just like any other code, it should be placed wherever it is needed.

Comment: So, I want to do something - but only after callSlides has started to do it's thing. I understand the logic - but not the syntax.

Comment: `callback` is a function, just call it like you would any other function.

Comment: @sheriffderek: There's no difference in syntax. A function call is a function call. Put it wherever it's needed.

Comment: Sorry if I'm stupid or something, but these answers are assuming that I understand the very thing I'm trying to explain that I do not. In my  example, would it go `}, callback` after the if statement?

Comment: If you want it invoked after the `if` statement, then yes, you'd put `callback();` after the `if` statement. And no, you don't  need a `,` after the closing `}` of the `if`. The `callback` part references the function you passed, and the `()` invokes the function. It's just like invoking any other function, just like you did when you invoked `callSlides`, except that you're not passing any arguments this time.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Thanks. I'm putting these pieces together and it's starting to make sense. I think I'm overthinking it.

Comment: NOTE TO SELF: I'm pretty sure this is the official day when I started actually learning JavaScript instead of pasting in some jQuery and hoping it worked. Now I'm a Sr. Product Designer and Consultant. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to place the "callback" towards the end of the function you wish to fire an event once it's done its business.

```
function mySpecialFunction(param1,param2,callback) {
  // Do some stuff. 

  // Do some more stuff.

  // Do even more stuff.

  // Check if the callback param exists and execute it if so. 
  if(callback) {
   callback();
  }
}
```

Usage : Here we just pass an inline function as the callback.

```
mySpecialFunction('foo', 'bar', function() {
  alert('I was called back.');
});
```

Or say you had another function you wanted to run called AlterUi. You can define that function somewhere else in the code and reference it as a callback to mySpecialFunction like this.

```
mySpecialFunction('foo', 'bar', AlterUi);
```

Hope this helps!